# Scala Akka code terminating early

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Hey guys im new to scala and akka so i was just trying things out..
But i cant understand why my code is terminating early. it is working but not till the end.
the last actor mike terminated before 1000.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props, ActorSystem}
class Person extends Actor with ActorLogging {
def receive = {
    case FullPint(number) =>
        log.info(s"Comsuming pint $number")
        log.info(s"Consumed pint $number")
        sender ! EmptyPint(number)
    }
}

class BarTender extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    var totalOrders = 0
    var totalEmpty = 0
    def receive = {
        case Ticket(quantity) =>
            totalOrders += quantity
            log.info(s"Serving up $quantity pints to [${sender.path}]")
            for(number <- 1 to quantity) {
                log.info(s"Preparing pint $number for [${sender.path}]")
                log.info(s"Sending pint $number to [${sender.path}]")
                log.info(s"$totalOrders ----- $totalEmpty")
                sender ! FullPint(number)
            }
        case EmptyPint(number) =>
            totalEmpty = totalEmpty + 1
            if(totalEmpty == totalOrders) {
                log.info("Bar is shutting down")
                context.system.shutdown()
            }
    }
}

case class Ticket(quantity:Int)
case class FullPint(number:Int)
case class EmptyPint(number:Int)

object HowdyAkka extends App {
    val system = ActorSystem("howdy")

    val zed = system.actorOf(Props(new BarTender), "zed")

    val alice = system.actorOf(Props(new Person), "alice")
    val bob = system.actorOf(Props(new Person), "bob")
    val mike = system.actorOf(Props(new Person), "mike")

    zed.tell(Ticket(3), alice)
    zed.tell(Ticket(2), bob)
    zed.tell(Ticket(1000), mike)

   system.awaitTermination()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possible sequence below:

- bartender receives Ticket(3) for alice
- bartender: totalOrders -> 3, three FullPint messages sent to alice
- alice: processes 3 FullPint messages in sequence, returning EmptyPint messages
- bartender receives the three EmptyPint messages before it receives the next Ticket message
- bartender: totalEmpty -> 3, = totalOrders: call to shutdown made
- bartender now processes next Ticket(2) for bob, totalOrders -> 5, etc...

... short while later, but well before mike processes all 1000 pints ...

- shutdown catches up with system, and program ends.

There's no guarantee that messages sent from different sources will arrive in any particular order at an actor's mailbox, only that a single given source's messages will arrive in order. So, the `Ticket`s will arrive in the `BarTender`'s mailbox in order, but the `EmptyPint` messages from `alice` may possibly get into the `BarTender`'s mailbox before the next `Ticket`, enabling the sequence above and confounding your expectations.

Comment: Yeah i had thought of that but the thing is when you run this and if the situation you described was happening then i should i have gotten the message Bar is Shutting Down but i dont get that message.

Comment: @Sidhant Fair point. Sorry, not sure what else might be going wrong then.